# React destructuring applied in a native JS project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm going through a React + Redux tutorial where there is a code snippet such as this:

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      articles: [
        { title: "React Redux Tutorial for Beginners", id: 1 },
        { title: "Redux e React: cos'è Redux e come usarlo con React", id: 2 }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { articles } = this.state;
    return <ul>{articles.map(el => <li key={el.id}>{el.title}</li>)}</ul>;
  }
}
```

Then, out of curiosity I did a simillar thing but in a non-react environment (eg. in console log in the browser). First I initialized a `constant` like this:

```
const articles = [
    { title: "React Redux Tutorial for Beginners", id: 1 },
    { title: "Redux e React: cos'è Redux e come usarlo con React", id: 2 }
]
```

But what confuses me is the `destructuring` part after which I get `undefined`. Like this:

```
const { someObj } = articles;
undefined
someObj
undefined
{ someObj }
{someObj: undefined}
someObj.title
VM205:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:9
```

My question is, why `const { articles } = this.state;` works fine, but `const { someObj } = articles;` returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying in the wrong way. You have an object here and it has an array:

```
const obj = { arr: [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
```

Instead of using like `obj.arr` you are destructuring the arr like that:

```
const { arr } = obj;
```

And use that variable directly with its name as `arr`.

If you want to destructure any item from an array you can use array destructring:

```
const [ number1, number2, number3 ] = arr;
```

If you want to combine those steps:

```
const { arr: [ number1, number2, number3 ] } = obj;
```

So right side is the destructured variable and the left side is the variables that you are destructring from the original one.
Also see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: In addition to this: it is also possible to destructure an array with `const [ article1, article2 ] = articles` - https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operatoren/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring

Comment: Thanks. I've added the array example.

Answer (score 1):

Because `this.state` is an `Object`, and your `articles` variable is an `Array`.

Object destructing syntax:

```
const { var1, var2 } = obj;
```

is equal to

```
const var1 = obj.var1;
const var2 = obj.var2;
```

Array destructing syntax:

```
const [arr1, arr2, ...arr3] = arr;
```

is equal to

```
const arr1 = arr[0];  
const arr2 = arr[1];
const arr3 = arr.slice(2);
```

You can see more here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment