# Having trouble managing states in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have been practicing JavaScript and ReactJs and I have been stuck on a problem for a while. Basically, I am trying to rewrite my HTML, CSS, Javascript project using ReactJs.

Here is my problem: (in regards to the React code). Say I click on the first answer choice for Question 1, the **class name** changes hence, styling changes(background becomes black) AND **isClicked** becomes true (both are states inside the EachIndividualAnswer class). If I then click on the **second answer choice**, I want the style for the first answer choice (and every other answer choice for that question) to be null, and isClicked to be false and **ONLY the second answer will have isClicked === true and className="clicked".**

Hope this makes sense. Sorry for sending so many files, Didn't know any other way.

Thanks

MY HTML, CSS AND JAVASCRIPT CODE. (the code I am trying to re-write with ReactJs)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var numberOfQuestions = 5;
var choicesPerQuestion = 5;

var questionNumber = document.getElementsByClassName("questionNumber");

var question = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("answers");

var answer_A = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_A");

var answer_B = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_B");

var answer_C = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_C");

var answer_D = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_D");

var answer_E = document.getElementsByClassName("answer_E");


var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

// Answer key

var answerKey = [21, 3, "Nani", "Kevin Durant", "Russ"];

var userAnswerArray = new Array(5);


// Put every single possible clickable answer in 5x5 array

// clicking an answer changes its background and color

var individual_answers = new Array(numberOfQuestions);


for(let i=0; i<numberOfQuestions; i++) {
 individual_answers[i] = new Array(choicesPerQuestion);
}


// Adding Event listeners to each answer choice

for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
 specificAnswers = answers[i].getElementsByTagName("li"); // answers to each questions e.g. answers to qu.1, then qu.2

 for (let j = 0; j < specificAnswers.length; j++) {
  individual_answers[i][j] = specificAnswers[j]; // individual answers to each qu.
  var spanX = individual_answers[i][j].getElementsByTagName("span"); // did not use this
  individual_answers[i][j].addEventListener("click", click(i , j));
 }

}

function click(i, j) {
 return function() {
  console.log(individual_answers[i][j].innerText);

  if(individual_answers[i][j].style.background != "black") { // if it's not black, set all to white, then put specific one to black

   for(let x=0; x<choicesPerQuestion; x++) {
    individual_answers[i][x].style.cssText = "background: white";
    individual_answers[i][x].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.color = "black";
   }
   individual_answers[i][j].style.cssText = "background: black";
   individual_answers[i][j].style.color = "green";
   individual_answers[i][j].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.color = "white";

   userAnswerArray[i] = individual_answers[i][j].innerText; 
   // i = question number, j = specific answer to question number i
   // So on each click, if answer originally doesn't have a black background, add it to userArray

  }
  else { // If background is black, on click you have to remove that from individual array
   individual_answers[i][j].style.cssText = "background: white";
   individual_answers[i][j].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.color = "black";
   userAnswerArray.splice(i, 1);
  }

 }
}

// Adding event listener to submit button
submit.addEventListener("click", score);

/* Easiest thing to do would be to make an "Answer class" for each answer. (using prototypes) with field selected.
Then count the number of answers with fields selected and compare with answer key or smthn. Try this as an exercise for later, maybe ReactJs */

/* For now I will create an array for the answers that will change as the user clicks and use the actual words to see if they match */

function score() {
 /* Add a check later to see if he has answered every question or at least 60% */

 var counter = 0;

 for(let x=0; x<numberOfQuestions; x++) {
  if(answerKey[x] == userAnswerArray[x]) {
   counter++;
  }
 }

console.log("User has submitted the quiz and scored " + counter);

if(counter < 3) {
 alert("Try again, you failed");
}

else {
 alert("Are you a lizard?")
}

/* Show on a message and ask to retake*/

}
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: square;
}

ul > li {
 color: blue;
 font-size: 30px;
}

ul > li > span {
 color: black;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#submit {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!--I will try to create a multiple choice exam. The user can NOT submit until he has answered 60% of the questions. Once he submits
I will show him his score. Give him the option to see which questions he failed, as well as the right answer. -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Multiple Choice Exam</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mcq.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>NASA Final Entry Exam</h1>
            <h2>Only the most genius of individuals will pass</h2>

            <br>
            <hr>
            <br>

            <p class="question"><span class="questionOne">1</span>. What is 9+10</p>
            <ul class="answers" id="answers1">
                <li class="answer_A"><span>1</span></li>
                <li class="answer_B"><span>19</span></li>
                <li class="answer_C"><span>21</span></li>
                <li class="answer_D"><span>90</span></li>
                <li class="answer_E"><span>-1<span></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="question"><span class="questiontwo">2</span>. How many goals did Ronaldo score against Spain in the World Cup 2018</p>
            <ul class="answers">
                <li class="answer_A"><span>1</span></li>
                <li class="answer_B"><span>3</span></li>
                <li class="answer_C"><span>5</span></li>
                <li class="answer_D"><span>0</span></li>
                <li class="answer_E"><span>-1<span></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="question"><span class="questionThree">3</span>. Who Stole Ronaldo's (CR7) greates ever goal?</p>
            <ul class="answers">
                <li class="answer_A"><span>Pepe</span></li>
                <li class="answer_B"><span>Messi</span></li>
                <li class="answer_C"><span>Casillas</span></li>
                <li class="answer_D"><span>Benzema</span></li>
                <li class="answer_E"><span>Nani<span></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="question"><span class="questionFour">4</span>. Which one of these players ruined the NBA</p>
            <ul class="answers">
                <li class="answer_A"><span>Allen Iverson</span></li>
                <li class="answer_B"><span>Kevin Durant</span></li>
                <li class="answer_C"><span>Steph Curry</span></li>
                <li class="answer_D"><span>Lebron James</span></li>
                <li class="answer_E"><span>Russel Westbrook<span></li>
            </ul>

            <p class="question"><span class="questionFive">5</span>. Who is currently number 1 in the internet L ranking?</p>
            <ul class="answers">
                <li class="answer_A"><span>Drake</span></li>
                <li class="answer_B"><span>Pusha T</span></li>
                <li class="answer_C"><span>Russel WestBrook</span></li>
                <li class="answer_D"><span>Lil Xan</span></li>
                <li class="answer_E"><span>Russ<span></li>
            </ul>

            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
        
        <script src="mcq.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

HERE IS MY REACJS PROJECT SO FAR. Wasn't sure on how to properly upload these files:

```
[App.js]

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Title from './Title/Title';
import Question from './Question/Question';
import Aux from './hoc/Aux';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0,
    questionArray: [
      "What is 9+10",
      "How many goals did Ronaldo score against Spain in the World Cup 2018",
      "Who Stole Ronaldo's (CR7) greates ever goal?",
      "Which one of these players ruined the NBA",
      "Who is currently number 1 in the internet L rankings?"
  ],
    answerChoicesArray: [
      ["1", "19", "21", "90", "-1"],
      ["1", "3", "5", "0", "-1"],
      ["Pepe", "Messi", "Casillas", "Benzema", "Nani"],
      ["Allen Iverson", "Kevin Durant", "Steph Curry", "Lebron James", "Russel Westbrook"],
      ["Drake", "Pusha T", "Russel Westbrook", "Lil Xan", "Russ"]
    ]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="container">
          <Aux>
            <Title />
            <h2>Only the most genius of individuals will pass</h2>
            <hr/>
            <Question
              questionArray={this.state.questionArray}
              answerChoicesArray={this.state.answerChoicesArray} />
            <button
            onClick={() => alert("We don't support this yet")}
            type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
          </Aux>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

.

.

```
[Question.js]

import React from 'react';
import AnswerChoices from '../AnswersChoices/AnswerChoices';

const Question = (props) => // why doesn't it work if I put a curly brace here
    props.questionArray.map((question, index) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <p>{index + 1}. {question}</p>

                <AnswerChoices
                    index={index} // try just index answersArray is the array of ALL answers
                    answerChoicesArray={props.answerChoicesArray} /> 
            </div>
    );
})

export default Question;
```

.

.
    [AnswerChoices.js]

```
import React from 'react';
import SpecificAnswerChoice from './SpecificAnswerChoice/SpecificAnswerChoice'

const AnswerChoices = (props) => {
    console.log(props.answerChoicesArray[props.index]);
        return (
            // 5 answers array for each question
            <div>
                <ul>
                <SpecificAnswerChoice 
                    answers={props.answerChoicesArray[props.index]}/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default AnswerChoices;
```

.

.

```
[SpecificAnswerChoice.js]

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import EachIndividualAnswer from './EachIndividualAnswer/EachIndividualAnswer'

    class SpecificAnswerChoice extends Component {
        // If I click once, set all to white and specific to black
        state = {
            resetClicksState: true // can start w/ false then change to always true inside resetClicks function
        }

        resetClicks = () => {
            console.log("TEST");
        }


        render() {

            // const style = {
            //     backgroundColor: 'white'
            // };


            return(  
                this.props.answers.map(individualAnswer => {
                    return (
                        <EachIndividualAnswer
                            className={this.state.class}
                            individualAnswer={individualAnswer}
                            resetClicks={this.resetClicks}
                            // onClick={this.clickHandler}
                            />
                    );
                })          
            )
        }
    }

    export default SpecificAnswerChoice;


    import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

.

.
    [EachIndividualAnswer.js]

```
class EachIndividualAnswer extends Component {
    state = {
        isClicked: false,
        class: ""
    }

    // clickHandler = (style) => {
    //     if(style.backgroundColor === 'white') {
    //         style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    //         style.color = 'white';
    //     }
    // }

    onClickHandler = () => {
        console.log(this.state.isClicked);
        console.log("djhfdf");
        if(this.state.isClicked) {
            var tempClass=""
            this.setState({
                isClicked: false,
                class: tempClass
            });
        } else {
            tempClass="clicked"
            this.setState({
                isClicked: true,
                class:tempClass
            })
        }
        this.props.resetClicks();
    }



    // testingOnClick = () => {
    //     console.log("If this works then I have 2+ functions on OnClick");
    // }

    // if props.resetClicks is true, which it always is, className='', isClicked=false for EVERY
    // EachIndividualAnswer. Then I do my logc that I already had
    render() {

        return (<li 
                    className={this.state.class}
                    onClick={this.onClickHandler}>
                    <span>
                        {this.props.individualAnswer}
                    </span>
                </li>);
    }
}

export default EachIndividualAnswer;
```

.

.

```
[Aux.js]

const aux = (props) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).

Comment: What @Tholle said and also what errors do you get when you attempt to build it?

Comment: @Tholle, how about my answer including the trick that I learned from you :)

Comment: @Tholle, I've even improved it after seeing your last answer. Damn, I like SO. Learning by trying to teaching :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible answer if I understood you right. I'm totally mimicking the situation so this is not a complete solution for you.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    answers: [ "1", "19", "21", "90", "-1" ],
    selected: {},
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    const {answer} = e.target.dataset;
    this.setState({selected:{
      [answer]: !!answer,
    }})
  };


  render() {
    const {answers} = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.selected);
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
        {
          answers.map( answer => 
            <li
            data-answer={answer}
            className={
                  this.state.selected[answer] ? 'colored' : ''
            }
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            >{answer}
            </li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here, we are using a `selected` state to hold the selected situation and according to this situation we are adding our class or set it to null. Our `handleClick` function does this selection change. There is a `console.log` in the render method so you can see what is going on here.

Also, I used dataset here to get the value since I don't like binding functions in JSX. With `.bind` it can be like that. Only the relevant parts:

```
handleClick2 = answer =>
   this.setState({
     selected: {
       [answer]: !!answer,
     }
})
```

and

```
onClick={this.handleClick2.bind(this, answer)}
```

One other possible solution to here, instead of doing this logic in your `EachIndividualAnswer` component you can do it in your `SpecificAnswerChoice` component. I mean holding the state and having `handleClick` handler. So, you can pass this handler to your `EachIndividualAnswer` with the `answer` than with your callback you can set the state in the `EachIndividualAnswer`. So, there will be no need to use datasets or `.bind`.

Lastly, as other says in the comments you should share a minimal code where you have problems. So, people can look your code easily and do their best.

If you think holding long answers as object properties is silly, here is another answer using array indexes of answers:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    answers: [ "1", "19", "21", "90", "-1" ],
    selected: {},
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    const {index} = e.target.dataset;
    this.setState({selected:{
      [index]: !!index,
    }})
  };


  render() {
    const {answers} = this.state;
    console.log(this.state.selected);
    return (
      <div>
      <ul>
        {
          answers.map( (answer, index) => 
            <li
            data-index={index}
            className={
                  this.state.selected[index] ? 'colored' : ''
            }
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            >{answer}
            </li>
          )
        }
      </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit after questions in comments**

```
const {answers} = this.state
```

This is Javascript's destructuring assignment syntax. We are just picking a property from the `this.state` object. Shorthand version of this code:

```
const answers = this.state.answers;
```

At first this could be seem not so useful but you can pick as many property as you want in an object. Think about a crowded object and you just need just three of them:

```
const { one, two, three } = object;
```

This is the shorthand of:

```
const one = object.one;
const two = object.two;
const three = object.three;
```

Very useful. For further information just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49711639/7060441) and of course [the official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You can see destructring all around React world since some people tend to use where it is suitable. It may not be always so nice when it is overused. It makes harder to read the code sometimes. But when you use it in the suitable places, it saves time and even makes readability better.

We are keeping answers here in our state. In your original code you are getting them as props. I will provide another answer after doing the explanation based on props. `selected` is the real deal here, state that we keep our selected elements.

```
this.setState({selected:{ [answer]: !!answer }})
```

Yes, this is a little bit awkward. We are using computed property for objects. So, we can use variables in an object's property. `[answer]`, this is what we use. So, in the `selected` state we are setting a property which name is our `answer` variable. Now, we use the right hand side to use our value to a boolean and we are setting it always to true in the first state change.

`answer` variable is a string here. In Javascript if you use logical not, `!` , operator on a string it evaluates to `false`. So we are using it twice to get `true`. For example, when we click on "19" this would be like this:

```
selected: {
    "19": !!"19"
}
```

You can try `!!"19"` in Javascript console, you will get `true`. Instead of using real values, we are just using variables here: `[answer]: !!answer`

Now, I will change this syntax a little bit in my last code example. If you look `setState`'s documentation you will see it is an asynchronous operation. So, React team discourages us to use it directly like this, especially if we use previous state of any piece in our state. Actually we are not doing it like that in our example but it is better using a callback for `this.setState`. Please go and read [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) if this explanation is not enough for you. Here how we use it this time:

```
  handleClick = answer => {
    this.setState(prevState =>
      ({
        selected: {
          [answer]: !prevState.selected.answer,
        }
      })
    )
  };
```

As you can see `setState` here takes a callback and uses `prevState` (or what name you give it) to react the previous state. Now, since there is not any `selected.answer` in our previous state, it is `undefined` in the first place. So, we can use `!prevState.selected.answer` to make the value `true` instead of using two logical not operand here. Remember, in the previous example we have a string here not an undefined value. This is why we use two logical not operand there.

Now, here is the last code that suits your situation. You are getting answers as prop and then render another component to show those. I use three components like you then render the individual answers.

```js
const answers = ["1", "19", "21", "90", "-1"]
const AnswerChoices = () => (
  <SpecificAnswerChoice answers={answers} />
)

class SpecificAnswerChoice extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: {},
  }

  handleClick = answer =>
    this.setState(prevState =>
      ({
        selected: {
          [answer]: !prevState.selected.answer,
        }
      })
    );

  
  render() {
    const { answers } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          answers.map( individualAnswer => (
            <EachIndividualAnswer
            individualAnswer={individualAnswer}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            selected={this.state.selected}
            key={individualAnswer}
          />
          ) )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// Again, destructring. Instead of (props) we use ({....})
// and pick our individual props here.
const EachIndividualAnswer = ({selected,individualAnswer, onClick}) => {
  const handleClick = () => onClick(individualAnswer)
  return (
    <div>
    <ul>
        {
          <li
            onClick={handleClick}
            className={
              selected[individualAnswer] ? 'colored' : ''
            }
          >{individualAnswer}
          </li>
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<AnswerChoices />, rootElement);
```

```css
.colored {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I declared `EachIndividualAnswer` component as a functional one since it does not need to be a class. Also, I pass a `handleClick` prop for click event. With this handler, child sends the answer and parent component gets back it and updates its state. One prop `EachIndividualAnswer` gets is `selected` state. So it decides whether add a class or not. So, our `selected` state resides in `SpecificAnswerChoice` component and child gets it as a prop. Lastly, this component gets `answers` from its parent as you can see.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your clear answer. Sorry again for the long code, I didn't know how to ask my question. I will try to apply your logic in a bit but I have a few questions and need a few clarifications because I'm very new to React. I will be referring to your first chunk of code. You wrote code like this: const {answers} = this.state; what do the curly braces mean in this case? And {answers} takes both the answers and selected states right? 
Also what does this mean: 
    this.setState({selected:{
          \[answer\]: !!answer,
        }})
makes no sense to me

Comment: You are welcome. No problem at all asking your problem in not a suitable way this time. For the next one you know now how can you do that :) I've edited my answer and add explanations for the code. Also, I've added a final code example that suits you more.